# Cannot get debconf version after delete /var/lib/dpkg

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

As a new ubuntu user, I just make a mistaken. 
I've deleted a folder /var/lib/dpkg/ instead of /var/lib/dpkg/lock.

Now when I execute apt-get -f install then it will display error message:

```
...
E: Cannot get debconf version. Is debconf installed?
debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: No such file or directory
...
```

I've try this tutorial: http://people.adams.edu/~cdmiller/posts/Ubuntu-dpkg-recovery/ but still no luck.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ubuntu really need to work with this little problem, there are many people who had same problem, ever try these solutions?

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-mint-84/dpkg-directory-re-create-862558/
https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/70504

Comment: replacing `/var/lib/dpkg/status` with a backup from `/var/backups/dpkg.status.*` worked for me